# Sharepoint Online connect to Exchange server

Tags: sharepoint-online, exchange-server

I have no experience with AD nor with Exchange server but have been tasked with setting up a SP online intranet for a company using Azure AD and office pro plus and have their own on prem exchange server.

Although i am able to get some user and group details within the SP online, i cannot do some things and would like advice;

- using workflows (2010) fails with *The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.* [image: workflow error]
- using Power Automate fails with T*he request failed. Error code: 'InvalidApprovalCreateRequestAssignedToNoValidUsers'. Error Message: 'Required field 'assignedTo' contained no valid users in the organization'.*[image: power automate error]
- some user profile details (profile image) are not pulled in SP [image]

Many thanks